# SSIS AcquireConnection method call to the connection manager "Excel Connection Manager"

Tags: sql-server, excel, ssis, ssis-2012

I am trying to take a table from a SQL Server database and place it into an excel document. It is a simple Source SQL Server to Destination of an Excel 97-2003 document. When I try to run this task though, I get the following error. I don't have Excel open and cannot seem to figure out why this is stopping me from doing this. I am on a 64-Bit Windows 7 computer.

```
Error: 0xC020801C at Data Flow Task 1, Excel Destination [2]: SSIS Error Code DTS_E_CANNOTACQUIRECONNECTIONFROMCONNECTIONMANAGER.  The AcquireConnection method call to the connection manager "Excel Connection Manager" failed with error code 0xC0209303.  There may be error messages posted before this with more information on why the AcquireConnection method call failed.
Error: 0xC0047017 at Data Flow Task 1, SSIS.Pipeline: Excel Destination failed validation and returned error code 0xC020801C.
Error: 0xC004700C at Data Flow Task 1, SSIS.Pipeline: One or more component failed validation.
Error: 0xC0024107 at Data Flow Task 1: There were errors during task validation.
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to change the property 
1)Right Click on the first Folder on Solution Explorer
2)Click on Properties and go Config. Debugging Prop. and set 'run64bitRuntime' to False

**Visit this site if there is a confusion.**

**  https://imgalib.wordpress.com/2013/01/24/how-to-solve-ssis-error-code-0xc020801c0xc004700c0xc0047017/